# Select data where date is the first and second half of the month (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, date

How to retrieve the data where the dates are between the 1st to the 15th of the month when the system date is between the 1st to the 15th day of the month, and when the system date is between the 16th and the end of the month, it will automatically retrieve the data between the 16th and 30th/31st of the month?

Please help me.

I have this code.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTimeIn), 0)) AS [Date],
    CONVERT(TIME(0),DateTimeIn) AS [Time In], CONVERT(TIME(0),DateTimeOut) AS [Time Out],
    Late, Undertime, AWOL, Leave 
FROM 
    tblAttendance2
WHERE 
    UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM tblUsers WHERE Username = @Username) 
    AND MONTH(DateTimeIn) = MONTH(GetDate())
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, DateTimeIn, 101) ASC
```

This shows the data of the whole current month.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on integer maths to work it out quite straightforwardly:

```
WHERE 
UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM tblUsers WHERE Username = @Username) 
AND DATEPART(month,DateTimeIn) = DATEPART(month,GetDate())
AND DATEPART(day,DateTimeIn)/16 = DATEPART(day,GetDate())/16
```

Basically, any number from 0-15, when divided by 16 will produce the value 0. Any number from 16-31 when divided by 16 will produce the value 1.

(I also switched to [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) <strike>because I'm a snob</strike> because that's how I wrote the day code before I integrated it into your query, and because I like the consistency of this method - in that it can be applied to retrieve any datetime portion, whereas [`MONTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) has counterparts in [`DAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) and [`YEAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) but there are no similar functions to retrieve e.g. the hour)

Answer (score 0):

Sybase solution (for other DBMS, check the "datepart" function equivalend, should be the same in MSSQL.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTimeIn), 0)) AS [Date],
    CONVERT(TIME(0),DateTimeIn) AS [Time In], CONVERT(TIME(0),DateTimeOut) AS [Time Out],
    Late, Undertime, AWOL, Leave 
FROM 
    tblAttendance2
WHERE 
    UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM tblUsers WHERE Username = @Username) 
    AND MONTH(DateTimeIn) = MONTH(GetDate())
    AND
    (
        (datepart(day, GetDate() <= 15 AND datepart(day, DateTimeIn) <= 15) 
        OR
        (datepart(day, GetDate() > 15 AND datepart(day, DateTimeIn) > 15)
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, DateTimeIn, 101) ASC
```

Basically the same than other solution, but more self-speaking (in my opinion...).